# Is it possible to run a zero-inflated negative binomial model with complete separation?

Tags: categorical-data, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation, overdispersion, separation

I am trying to analyze how the number of events Y is influenced by three factors A (4 levels), B (2 levels) and C (2 levels) and the interactions between the three.

Initially trying a poisson regression found the model to be over-dispersed so a negative binomial regression was run.

```
model <- glm(No.Y ~ A*B*C, data=Y,  family = poisson)

#Checks for overdispersal
#Method 1
library(DHARMa)
Y.simresid <- simulateResiduals(model, refit=T)
testDispersion(Y.simresid)

    DHARMa nonparametric dispersion test via mean deviance residual fitted
    vs. simulated-refitted

data:  Y.simresid
dispersion = 50.315, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two.sided

#Method 2
library(AER)
dispersiontest(model)

Overdispersion test

data:  model
z = 10.075, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true dispersion is greater than 1
sample estimates:
dispersion 
  45.68352
```

Re-checking for overdispersal in the negative binomial regression found the model to still be over-dispersed so a check for zero-inflation was done which found the model to be zero-inflated

```
library(MASS)
model.nb<-glm.nb(No.Y ~ A*B*C, link = "log", data = Y)
summary(model.nb)
testDispersion(model.nb)

DHARMa nonparametric dispersion test via sd of residuals fitted vs.
    simulated

data:  simulationOutput
ratioObsSim = 6.735, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two.sided

#It should also be noted that the following error message occurs when I try to run the negative binomial model

Warning messages:
1: In theta.ml(Y, mu, sum(w), w, limit = control$maxit, trace = control$trace >  :
  iteration limit reached
2: In sqrt(1/i) : NaNs produced
3: In theta.ml(Y, mu, sum(w), w, limit = control$maxit, trace = control$trace >  :
  iteration limit reached
4: In sqrt(1/i) : NaNs produced

#Testing for zero-inflation
library(performance)
check_zeroinflation(model.nb)

Observed zeros: 8
  Predicted zeros: 0
            Ratio: 0.00

Model is underfitting zeros (probable zero-inflation).
```

Due to this I tried to run a zero-inflated negative binomial model

```
library(pscl)
model.zinb <- zeroinfl((No.Y) ~ A*B*C | A*B*C, dist = "negbin", link = "logit", data = Y)
summary(model.zinb)

Call:
zeroinfl(formula = (No.Y) ~ A * B * C | A * B * C, data = Y, dist = "negbin", link = "logit")

Pearson residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.98410 -0.53126  0.09794  0.57463  2.70958 

Count model coefficients (negbin with log link):
                                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                           5.529870   0.153303  36.072   <2e-16 ***
A2                                   -0.011080   0.193922  -0.057    0.954    
A3                                    0.060285   0.216744   0.278    0.781    
A4                                   -0.270010   0.206984  -1.305    0.192    
B2                                    0.098549   0.216708   0.455    0.649    
C2                                   -0.257898   0.211589  -1.219    0.223    
A2:B2                                 0.095450   0.301974   0.316    0.752    
A3:B2                                -0.001112   0.282889  -0.004    0.997    
A4:B2                                 0.330683   0.304416   1.086    0.277    
A2:C2                                 0.252536   0.287025   0.880    0.379    
A3:C2                                -0.207106   0.299325  -0.692    0.489    
A4:C2                                 0.180624   0.281667   0.641    0.521    
B2:C2                                -0.161818   0.314105  -0.515    0.606    
A2:B2:C2                             -0.001083   0.449043  -0.002    0.998    
A3:B2:C2                              0.425869   0.406000   1.049    0.294    
A4:B2:C2                              0.051666   0.412524   0.125    0.900    
Log(theta)                            1.572384   0.104317  15.073   <2e-16 ***

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
                                       Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)                          -2.057e+01  9.744e+03  -0.002    0.998
A2                                    1.786e+01  9.744e+03   0.002    0.999
A3                                    1.837e+01  9.744e+03   0.002    0.998
A4                                    1.886e+01  9.744e+03   0.002    0.998
B2                                    1.837e+01  9.744e+03   0.002    0.998
C2                                   -4.321e-08  1.343e+04   0.000    1.000
A2:B2                                -3.623e+01  1.473e+04  -0.002    0.998
A3:B2                                -1.926e+01  9.744e+03  -0.002    0.998
A4:B2                                -1.874e+01  9.744e+03  -0.002    0.998
A2:C2                                -1.786e+01  1.659e+04  -0.001    0.999
A3:C2                                -1.837e+01  1.631e+04  -0.001    0.999
A2:C2                                -1.886e+01  1.554e+04  -0.001    0.999
B2:C2                                -1.837e+01  1.739e+04  -0.001    0.999
A2:B2:C2                              3.623e+01  2.573e+04   0.001    0.999
B2:B2:C2                              3.694e+01  1.970e+04   0.002    0.999
C2:B2:C2                              1.874e+01  2.016e+04   0.001    0.999
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Theta = 4.8181 
Number of iterations in BFGS optimization: 1 
Log-likelihood: -1139 on 33 Df
```

As can be seen in the summary output the coefficients and p-values for the zero part of the model look extremely off. I believe this to be as a result of complete separation as some of the A:B:C factor level combinations have no zero counts for Y.

As a result of this, my question is how do you deal with complete separation when using zero-inflated models in order to accurately interpret the zero part of the model?